# return object value to parent function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have been battling with code below. I actually want to know how to return the value of the inner object 'result' in the main function 'myfunc()'.

```
function myfunc(){

        con.connect(function(err){

            con.query(q,function(err){

                var result = 'mY Result';
            });

        });

    }
```

I just want to assign 'result' to 'myfunc()'. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the following approach:

```
// add async here to denote the method as awaitable to callers
async function myfunc(){

    // Wrap the inner logic with a promise. This allows you
    // return a result, when it is available
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        con.connect(function(err){

            con.query(q,function(err){

                // Once the inner functions complete, and
                // a result is available, we return that
                // result to external code by passing the
                // result to the 'resolve' function like
                // so:
                var result = 'mY Result';
                resolve(result)
            });

        });
    })
}
```

Now depending on how your project is setup, you will usually have two options for how you call `myfunc()`:

```
// Option #1
const queryResultOption1 = await myfunc()

// Option #2
myfunc().then(function(queryResult) {

    // Use queryResult here
})
```

Generally speaking, option #2 is the "older" way of doing things but offers more widespread support, where as option #1 is the "newer" way and tends towards code thats easier to read, reason about and work with, etc.

### Update

Note that there are some constraints when using `Option #2`. For instance, you can only call the `myfunc()` with `await` keyword in the context of an `async` method.

In other words, this means you can't just call `await myfunc()` directly if the place you're calling it from is not denoted `async`. So for example, to use this method directly in say, a nodejs entry script, you'd need to do something like this:

```
(async function () {

    const result = await myfunc()

})()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Dacre. I tried your option but I get 'await is only valid in async function'. It shows the message when I do 'console.log(await myfunc());'

Comment: Hi you're welcome - please see update with `async` keyword prefixing the method. hope this helps :-)

Comment: I really don't understand why I keep getting that error message 'await is only valid in async function' even after prefixing the function with the keyword `async`. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Ah, this will depending on the *context* that you're calling the `async` method from.  If you're just trying to call `myFunc` directly, and not in the context of an `async` function then it'll give you that error. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks @Dacre Denny. Your last update worked perfectly for me.